# is it possible to hide the footnote number reference in flextable footer section and replace with own text

Tags: r, flextable

I have a flextable:

```
df = data.frame(col1 = c(123,234,54,5), col2 = c(NA,1,2,3), col3 = 5:8)
df %>%
  flextable() %>%
  footnote(i = 1, j = 1,
           value = as_paragraph('this is a footnote'),
           ref_symbols = "1",
           part = "body") %>%
  footnote(i = 1, j = 1,
           value = as_paragraph(as_b("Note (2):"),"This is another foonote"),
           ref_symbols = "2",
           part = "body")
```

that shows

[image]

What I would like to do is keep the flextable and footnotes, but remove the little 1 and 2 that appear in the footer section.

Comment: use add_footer_line()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `add_footer_lines()` to add any content in a new line and `append_chunks()` to append any content in existing cells/rows/columns (`prepend_chunks()` can sometimes be useful)

```
library(flextable)
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(123,234,54,5), col2 = c(NA,1,2,3), col3 = 5:8)
df |>
  flextable() |>
  add_footer_lines("Here is a foonote") |> 
  add_footer_lines(as_paragraph(as_b("Note (2):"),"This is another foonote")) |> 
  append_chunks(i = 1, j = 1, as_sup("12")) |> 
  append_chunks(i = 2, j = 1, as_sup("‡"))
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not see the 2 in the body of the table with this method

Comment: Yes, there is 2 steps for you: (1) you will have to add these symbol manually (certainly before the creation of the table with `flextable::flextable`) and then, (2) use the function proposed by David Gohel to add a row in the footnote of the table (after the creation of the table)... see the other answer I've made previously.

Comment: I have updated the answer, sorry I did not understand the need to keep the symbols.

Comment: after showing your updated answer, this is more concise, thanks for checking again @DavidGohel

Comment: Nice answer., it's a - far - better solution to keep the footnote creation "inside" the flextable, my mistake...

Answer (score 1):

The David Gohel's previous answer is fine for not getting this behavior of adding the symbol in the cell and in the footnote, but this previous answer will not add "1" or "2" *in the cells of the table*. In this case, you have to add these symbols by yourself in the cells, since the `footnote` func' require a "value" parameter (or you get `Error in mapply(function(x, y) { :  argument "value" is missing, with no default`).

In order to add ¹, ², etc. in the cells of the table, I suggest to use a superscript generator (e.g., [here](https://lingojam.com/SuperscriptGenerator)), and a `paste0` func' to modify the cells and add the symbol ¹ to the data; then use the `add_footer_lines` func' to create the footnote that you want, without the symbol at the beginning of the footnote (see David Gohel's previous answer).

PS: for a good readability of the "ref_symbols", I prefer to use letters when the symbol appears next to a number (e.g., I use "† ", "‡ ", "A" or "B") and I add number-footnote-symbol when it come next to a text (e.g., ¹ or ²).

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to add this character pogramatically, without having to use the superscript generator? I have ~ 130 notes in 16 tables I would like to refer to, and needing to manually update all cells will be a bit tedious using this generator

Comment: Ok, I guess you've  stored the symbol in a data.frame or something like that? In that case, try to convert your symbol with the `common` package and the `common::supsc("1")` func' (passing it a character, nor a number) before "pasting" it into the right cell. In your case it would look something like:

 `mutate(df, the_superscript_symbol_for_my_footnotes = common::supsc(as.character(the_original_symbol)))`

Comment: It's fine if you like this solution, but I really think the data should not be altered; instead I prefer to use dedicated functions like `append_chunls()` :)